# Will Halo: Spartan Strike Achievements on the iOS version increase my gamerscore on my Xbox Live Account?

Tags: achievements, ios, halo-spartan-assault

I know of at least one iOS game that unlocked achievements on my Xbox Live account and it was called *Wordament*. I'm wondering if I play the new *Halo: Spartan Strike* game on iOS will it unlock achievements in my Xbox Live account like *Wordament* did? Or will it just be iOS achievements and not added to my overall Xbox Live gaming score? I don't own the game yet. I'm trying to figure out which platform to buy it on and this is a deciding factor for me.

Comment: Is there any log-in mechanism (apart from Game Center)? | As far as I know, the PC version doesn't have anything apart from (if purchased from Steam) achievements on Steam, and **that isn't linked to Game Center or XBL in any way**. Neither does the Win Store version.

Comment: I should add that I dont own the game. I'm thinking about buying it but I'd rather get it on a platform that has xbox achievements if possible. I prefer iOS if it has achievements that link with my xbox otherwise I'll get it on another platform that does.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, *pirated* copies do not work in any way (as you are required to buy it) and the game on other platforms are not interlinked in any way... The high-scores boards may be linked, but that it as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nope.

The iOS (okay... iPad) version of Halo: Spartan Assault is not linked with Xbox Live Arcade in any way, due to the way the APIs are handled in each version of the game. **The iOS version is locked to Game Center**.

Steam uses the Steam API (in `steam_api.dll`) to add achievements to a Steam account, the Windows Store app does not record (as far as I know) achievements, iOS links straight with Games Center while the XBLA version links with your gamertag.

Your only option for it to increase your gamerscore is to purchase it through the Xbox Live Arcade channel; platform.

---

This should be obvious since there is no way to log onto XBLA through any of the versions on the other platforms (apart from the Xbox version).

Comment: I only asked because Wordament and Wordament Snap Attack both are on iOS and they DO give you xbox live achievements.

Comment: @jimmyplaysdrums They are the ONLY games that have Live achievements on iOS.